# ¿Cómo parar todos los procesos a la vez?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un botón que inicia un setTimeout cada vez que lo pulso (no debería ser así, solo podría estar activo uno a la vez, pero bueno).

Imaginemos que tengo 3 setTimeout abiertos y quiero pararlos todos a la vez, intenté hacer un botón dinámico que los parase, y una vez parados, se borrase. Crear el botón una sola vez fue fácil, lo difícil, y que no me sale, es parar todos los procesos de una.

El código es este:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{

  document.querySelector('.magic').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    //creamos un boton para parar el ciclo
    let stop_btn = createStopBtn();
    if(!document.querySelector('.stop-btn')){
      document.body.appendChild(stop_btn);
    }
    var timer = false;
    startGame(stop_btn, timer);
  })
});

function startGame(stop_btn, timer){
  //obtener eel boton
  if(document.querySelector('.stop-btn') == null){
    console.log('timer has stopped');
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  else{
    document.querySelector('.stop-btn').onclick = function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      document.querySelector('.stop-btn').remove();
  }}
  //obtenemos un length
  let lng = document.querySelectorAll('.cont').length;
  //elegimos aleatoriamente un número entre 0 y el lenght
  let rng = randomNumber(lng);
  //obtenemos el cuadrado que queremos
  let dvc = getDivColored(rng);
  console.log(rng);

  if(dvc.style.backgroundColor == dvc.getAttribute('data')){
    dvc.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
  else{
    dvc.style.backgroundColor = dvc.getAttribute('data');
  }

  timer = setTimeout(startGame, 1000);
}

function randomNumber(lng){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(lng));
}

function getDivColored(rng){
  return document.querySelectorAll('.cont')[rng];
}

function createStopBtn(){
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
      btn.type='button';
      btn.innerHTML='STOP';
      btn.className='stop-btn'

  return btn
}
```

```css
.cont{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:0 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.red{
    background: red;
}
.blu{
    background: blue;
}
.yel{
    background: yellow;
}
.gre{
    background: green;
}
.pur{
    background: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>013 : paleta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/013.css">
    <script src="js/013.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="plt">
        <div class="red cont" data="red"></div>
        <div class="blu cont" data="blue"></div>
        <div class="yel cont" data="yellow"></div>
        <div class="gre cont" data="green"></div>
        <div class="pur cont" data="purple"></div>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="magic">MAGIA</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Como ven, si pulsamos dos veces al start se crean dos procesos simultáneos, y el botón stop solo puede llegar a parar uno.

Se que podría hacer el botón de start dinámico, y borrarlo cuando lo pulse. PERO, quiero aprender a hacer lo otro antes :3

¿Cómo podía hacerlo?

---

**[EDIT]**

Intentando implementar el array con los setTimeout de @Pablo Lozano, creo que la he liado un poco más...

Ahora mismo lo tengo así:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{

  document.querySelectorAll('.cont').forEach(item=>{
    item.addEventListener('click', (item)=>{
      let col = getColor(item.target);
      changeCol(col);
    });
  });

  document.querySelector('.magic').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    //creamos un boton para parar el ciclo
    let stop_btn = createStopBtn();
    if(!document.querySelector('.stop-btn')){
      document.body.appendChild(stop_btn);
    }
    //var timer;
    startGame(stop_btn);
  })
});

function getColor(item){
  return item.getAttribute('data');
}

function changeCol(col){
  if(document.body.style.backgroundColor != col){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = col;
  }
  else{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
}

function startGame(stop_btn){

    var timeouts= [];

    document.querySelector('.stop-btn').onclick = function(){
      while(timeouts.length){
        clearTimeout(timeouts.pop());
      }
    document.querySelector('.stop-btn').remove();
    }
        //obtenemos un length
  let lng = document.querySelectorAll('.cont').length;

  //elegimos aleatoriamente un número entre 0 y el lenght
  let rng = randomNumber(lng);

  //obtenemos el cuadrado que queremos
  let dvc = getDivColored(rng);

  //obtenemos data
  let data = dvc.getAttribute('data');

  //comprobamos selectores
  if(dvc.classList.contains(data)){
    dvc.classList.remove(data);
    dvc.classList.add('white');
  }
  else{
    dvc.classList.remove('white');
    dvc.classList.add(data);
  }

  //setTimeout activo
  //timer = setTimeout(startGame, 1000);
  timeouts.push(setTimeout(() => startGame(timeouts.length+1),1000));
}

function randomNumber(lng){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(lng));
}

function getDivColored(rng){
  return document.querySelectorAll('.cont')[rng];
}



function createStopBtn(){
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
      btn.type='button';
      btn.innerHTML='STOP';
      btn.className='stop-btn'

  return btn
}
```

```css
.cont{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:0 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.red{
    background-color: red;
}
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.green{
    background-color: green;
}
.purple{
    background-color: purple;
}
.white {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>013 : paleta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/013.css">
    <script src="js/013.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="plt">
        <div class="red cont" data="red"></div>
        <div class="blue cont" data="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow cont" data="yellow"></div>
        <div class="green cont" data="green"></div>
        <div class="purple cont" data="purple"></div>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="magic">MAGIA</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Meto los timeout dentro del array tal y como me explicó Pablo, pero a la hora de hacer un borrado universal de los mismos, si no detecta el botón, no lo hace.

Esto me dio para pensar que con un if (!boton) podría controlarlo, y si no lo detecta, haga el delete igualmente. Pero no funcionó.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a tener un número indeterminado de "timeouts" en cola, puedes usar un array para guardar los identificadores:

```js
let addBtn = document.querySelector("#addTimeout");
let cancelBtn = document.querySelector("#cancel");
let timeouts = [];
addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  timeouts.push(setTimeout(() => writeMessage(timeouts.length + 1), 5000));
});

cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("cancelando", timeouts.length, "ejecuciones pendientes")
  while (timeouts.length) {
     clearTimeout(timeouts.pop());
  }
});

function writeMessage(num) {
  document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML += `Mensaje número ${num}\n`;
  timeouts.shift();//Quito el id, ya se completó
}
```

```html
<button id="addTimeout"> Muestra un mensaje en 5 segundos </button>
<button id="cancel"> Cancela todas las colas </button>
<pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: Enseguida lo intento implementar en mi código. Muchas gracias