# setInterval se mete en un bucle autoincremental infinito

Tags: javascript

Me han dado una explicación breve del `setInterval()`, y es que dicho intervalo genera un id, por así decir, y aunque haga un `clearInterval()`, dicha id no la habré borrado del todo.

Con esta explicación que me han dado, ya no sabría resolver el problema que me está generando mi `setInterval()`:

```
function selectTurn(arg) {
    //console.log(arg);
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('turn-rest');
    const turn = setInterval(() => {
        arg.forEach((item, index) => {
            item.vel += item.trn;
            if (item.vel >= 100) {
                item.vel = 0;
                clearInterval(turn);
                item.ia(arg, item);
            }
            elements[index].style.width = item.vel + 'px';
        });
    },150);
}
```

Dicha función hace que, cuando el argumento `item.vel` en cuestión, alcance o supere 100, haga un `clearInterval` y llame a una función que tiene el item como argumento (`item.ia`).

La función hace lo que tenga que hacer, y vuelve a llamar a ESTA función, por lo que comienza el intervalo por donde lo dejó por ultima vez, pero con el anterior `item.vel` reseteado a 0.

El caso  es que, después de unos cuantos ciclos, el programa se vuelve loco, y deja de hacer los `clearInterval()`, e incrementando los `item.vel` de forma exponencial y no de forma constante.

No tengo forma de poder pararlo, incluso según la documentación lo estoy haciendo correctamente. He probado también a pasar la variable `turn` como argumento por la función y nada,es más, ni siquiera lo detiene desde un principio. De momento la opción más viable es tenerlo donde está, pero también está mal.

¿Qué puedo hacer para que no se vuelva esto loco?

Pd: Esto es el array arg:

```
const ent = [
    entity( 'arma-rubi' ,800000, 180, 200, 180, 100, 1, 0.8, armaRubiTurn, 0),
    entity( 'rubi-arm-1' ,180000, 120, 100, 60, 100, 1, 1.55, armUno, 0),
    entity( 'rubi-arm-2' ,180000, 60, 120, 120, 100, 1, 1.45, armDos, 0),
    entity( 'pj1' ,9999, 255, 255, 255, 100, 1, 1.8, player1Turn, 0),
    entity( 'pj2' ,9999, 255, 255, 255, 100, 1, 2.4, player2Turn, 0),
    entity( 'pj3' ,9999, 255, 255, 255, 100, 1, 1.95, player3Turn, 0)
    ];


function entity(name, hp, atk, def, mag, agi, vel, trn, ia, cont){
    return {
        name : name,
        hp : hp,
        atk: atk,
        def: def,
        mag: mag,
        agi: agi,
        vel : vel,
        trn : trn,
        ia : ia,
        cont : cont
    };
}
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Pongo un ejemplo de muestra de lo que hace item.ia() para ver el trigger de selectTurn();

```
function armUno(arg, item){//fisico
    item.cont++;
    console.log(item.cont);
    //seleccionar ataque
    let prc = parseInt((Math.random()*99)+1);

    if(prc <= 85){
        //seleccionamos objetivo
        let target = arg[parseInt(Math.random()*(6-3)+3)];
        let dmg = document.getElementsByClassName(target.name+'-dmged')[0];
            dmg.style.color = 'red';
        let rst = document.getElementsByClassName(target.name+'-hp-rest')[0];

        console.log('Atacando...');
        let rng = parseInt((item.atk*(Math.random()*(((item.atk/10)*2)-(item.atk/10))+(item.atk/10)))-target.def);//MAX : 2625 //min : 1185 
        //visualizar dmg
        dmg.innerHTML = rng;
        //restar vida
        target.hp -= rng;
        //visualizar restar vida
        rst.style.width = target.hp/99.99+'px';
        //acabar turno
        setTimeout(function(){dmg.innerHTML = '';selectTurn(arg)},3000);

    } else{
        console.log('Curando...');

        let hal = document.getElementsByClassName(arg[0].name+'-dmged')[0];
        let sum = document.getElementsByClassName(arg[0].name+'-hp-rest')[0];

        if(arg[0].hp == 800000){
            hal.innerHTML = 'MERMA';
        }
        else{
            hal.style.color = 'lime';
            //obtenemos valor
            let rng = parseInt(((item.mag/2)*(Math.random()*(((800000/1000)*0.12)-(800000/10000))+800000/10000)));//MAX : 2880 //min : 2400
            //visualzamos valor
            hal.innerHTML = rng;
            arg[0].hp += rng;
            sum.style.width = arg[0].hp/800+'px';
        }
        //acabar turno
        setTimeout(function(){hal.innerHTML = '';selectTurn(arg)},3000);
    }
```

Todos los ia tienen un setTimeout() para hacer trigger al selectTurn tal y como muestro aqui.

---

**[EDIT 2]**

---

Acabo de probar dos soluciones que me dieron. Una, el turn como función, y llamarla, tal y como en la respuesta de @Devandmus, al final, se sigue incrementando el número de intervalos y no respeta las paradas:

```
const turn = setInterval(turnInterval, 150);
  function turnInterval(){
    arg.forEach((item, index) => {
      item.vel += item.trn;
      if (item.vel >= 100) {
        item.vel = 0;
        clearInterval(turn);
        item.ia(arg, item);
      }
```

Otra forma fue declarando let turn; como variable global, y llamándola cuando fuera necesario, y tampoco, tarda un poquitín más, pero  se rompe al final.

Comment: Deberías agregar cómo son las funciones `ia`. Al menos algunas para que nos podamos hacer una idea de qué hacen. Con un ejemplo mínimo que he hecho, donde las funciones `ia` son `selectTurn`, el problema viene de que una vez un `item` tenga `vel > 100` e invoque a `ia`, los otros `item` potencialmente también, por lo que no es que sea un *interval* que se vuelve loco, sino que hay N *intervals* en paralelo, y N crece exponencialmente.

Comment: Yo definiría `turn` como variable en contexto global (`let turn;`) y no como constante dentro del método, dejando solo `turn = setInterval(() => { ... }, 150);`. De esta forma garantizas que no se crea una nueva variable (o constante) cada que se ejecuta la función y, en teoría, tendrías más control sobre el intervalo.

Comment: En mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442184/if-no-detecta-que-tenga-un-valor-a-9999/442204#442204) a tu pregunta anterior, evito que se vuelva a generar un nuevo `setInterval`, verificando si ya hay uno en ejecución. Para ello basta guardar el valor del `setInterval` en el objeto al que pertenece, supongamos que creas un campo que se llama `interval` en tu objeto `entity`, y lo estableces a `null`. Para ejecutar `selectTurn()` primero verificas si ya se tiene un `setInterval`, si no se tiene se puede crear uno y su identificador se guarda en ese campo...

Comment: ...luego, cuando haces `clearInterval` estableces también el campo `interval` a `null`, para que se pueda volver a ejecutar `selectTurn()` si es necesario. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Eso que comentas "que se vuelve loco", no tiene que ver con setInterval, más bien con su disparador. Verifica quién es el trigger de  `selectTurn(arg)` y bajo qué condiciones.

De igual forma, te propongo este código:

```javascript
const selectTurn(arg) => {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('turn-rest');
  const turn = setInterval(turnInterval, 150);
  function turnInterval(){
    arg.forEach((item, index) => {
      item.vel += item.trn;
      if (item.vel >= 100) {
        item.vel = 0;
        clearInterval(turn);
        item.ia(arg, item);
      }
    elements[index].style.width = item.vel + 'px';
  });
}
```

Comment: No hay ningún problema con el "*scope*" de `turn`. A efectos prácticos es la misma implementación.

Comment: Entonces es su trigger.

Comment: Edito y pongo un ejemplo del trigger

Answer (score 0):

Vale, gracias a @Pablo Lozano en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/438185/87282) me dio la solución. Crear un Array, usando la variable global turn, hacer un push del intervalo a dicho array, y hacer un while para cerrar tantos intervalos como length tenga dicho array:

```
let turn = [];

function selectTurn(arg) {
    //console.log(arg);
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('turn-rest');
    turn.push(setInterval(() => {
        arg.forEach((item, index) => {
            item.vel += item.trn;
            if (item.vel >= 100) {
                console.log(turn.length);
                item.vel = 0;
                item.ia(arg, item);
                while(turn.length){
                    clearInterval(turn.pop());
                }
            }
            elements[index].style.width = item.vel + 'px';

            document.addEventListener('keyup',(e)=>{
                if(e.key == 'Escape'){
                    clearInterval(turn)
                }
            })
        });
    },150));
}
```

Ahora mi pregunta es, comprobando su funcionamiento, a veces llego a tener 7 intervalos en el array, y me gustaría saber cómo y por qué se crean 7 de golpe en un turno.